# Access to the path 'Enrollments.zip' is denied, After running Background service running

Tags: c#, file, service, zip

After I restart my PC, my background service works fine. If I reinstalled or made any changes to the DB, my PC access path ".zip" denied. one more thing same background is running in another PC.

Two background services running in two different PCs to exchange the data.

Here's the code:

```
    public void GetFilesFromWebAPIAndCountTemplates(DateTime startTime,DateTime endTime,string webAPIURL,string code,string localPath)
    {           
        ZipLocationsCount zipLocation = null;
        count = 0;
        if (startTime < endTime)
        {
            WebApiCall apiCall = new WebApiCall();
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            var zipByteResponse = apiCall.CallZipWebApi(webAPIURL, "api/ZIPEnrollmentsDownload/ZIPResponse?startTime=" + startTime + "&endTime=" + endTime+ "&locationCode="+code, null, Constants.Get);
            lgmr.Log(string.Concat(serviceName, " ", code, ": Get Response From WebAPI successfully"), LoggingManager.LogType.Info);

            if (zipByteResponse.Result != null && zipByteResponse.Result.Length > 0)
            {
                string fileName = code + "_Enrollments.zip";

                try
                {                       
                    ConvertIntoZipAndMoveToBackUp(localPath, fileName, zipByteResponse.Result, code);
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    //GetFilesFromWebAPIAndCountTemplates(startTime, endTime, webAPIURL, code, localPath);  
                    ecount = 0;
                    strECount = "Fail to Zip";
                    lgmr.Log(string.Concat(serviceName, " ", code, " count:", ecount, ": Failed to Converted to ZIP", ex.StackTrace, ex.InnerException, ex.Message), LoggingManager.LogType.Error);
                    goto label1;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                ecount = 0;
                if(ecount == 0)
                {
                    strECount = "No Enrolments";
                }
                lgmr.Log(string.Concat(serviceName, " ", code, ": No Enrollments"), LoggingManager.LogType.Info);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lgmr.Log(string.Concat(serviceName, " ",code, ": Start Date Should be lass than End Date"), LoggingManager.LogType.Info);
        }

        FPSyncHistory fpSync = new FPSyncHistory();
        fpSync.LocationCode = code;
        fpSync.FromDate = startTime;
        fpSync.ToDate = endTime;
        fpSync.FPExported = ecount;
        fpSync.Status = true;
        fpSync.CreatedBy = 1;
        fpSync.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
        fPSyncHistories.Add(fpSync);

        label1:
        zipLocation = new ZipLocationsCount() { LocationCode = code, FromDate = startTime, ToDate = endTime, EnrollmentsCount = strECount };
        if (zipLocation.FromDate < zipLocation.ToDate)
        {
            zipLocationsCounts.Add(zipLocation);
        }
    }
```

the Above Method i am calling into another method

```
 public void GetZipResponseFromWebAPI()
    {
        try
        {                
            zipLocationsCounts = new List<ZipLocationsCount>();
            fPSyncHistories = new List<FPSyncHistory>();
            DateTime sTime = new DateTime();
            DateTime startTime = new DateTime();
            DateTime eTime = new DateTime();
            DateTime endTime = new DateTime();


            foreach (FPSyncLocationDetail fpLocation in tmlEntity.FPSyncLocationDetails)
            {                   
                var findHistory = tmlEntity.FPSyncHistories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LocationCode == fpLocation.Code);
                if (findHistory == null)
                {                      
                    if(fpLocation.Status == true)
                    {
                        sTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
                        startTime = new DateTime(sTime.Year, sTime.Month, sTime.Day, 00, 00, 00);
                        eTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
                        endTime = new DateTime(eTime.Year, eTime.Month, eTime.Day, 23, 59, 59);

                        GetFilesFromWebAPIAndCountTemplates(startTime,endTime,fpLocation.WebAPIURL,fpLocation.Code,fpLocation.LocalFPFolderPath);
                    }
                }
                else if (findHistory != null)
                {
                    var locationLastDates = from n in tmlEntity.FPSyncHistories
                                            group n by n.LocationCode into g
                                            select new { LocationCode = g.Key, ToDate = g.Max(t => t.ToDate) };
                    foreach (var loc in locationLastDates)
                    {
                        if (fpLocation.Code == loc.LocationCode)
                        {
                            if (fpLocation.Status == true)
                            {
                                sTime = loc.ToDate.AddDays(1);
                                startTime = new DateTime(sTime.Year, sTime.Month, sTime.Day, 00, 00, 00);
                                eTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
                                endTime = new DateTime(eTime.Year, eTime.Month, eTime.Day, 23, 59, 59);

                                GetFilesFromWebAPIAndCountTemplates(startTime, endTime, fpLocation.WebAPIURL, fpLocation.Code, fpLocation.LocalFPFolderPath);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }                              
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string InnerException = ex.InnerException != null ? ex.InnerException.ToString() : "";
            lgmr.Log(string.Concat("Error at GetZipResponseFromWebAPI", ex.StackTrace, ex.InnerException, ex.Message), LoggingManager.LogType.Error);
            return;
        }
    }
```

finally CallWebAPI method logic below

```
 public async Task<byte[]> CallZipWebApi(String WebApiUri, String uri, StringContent obj, string type)
    {           
        try
        {
            count++;
           HttpResponseMessage resMeg;
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"));
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(WebApiUri);
                lgmr.Log(string.Concat(uri,": Sending Request to WebAPI"), LoggingManager.LogType.Info);
                if (type == Constants.Get)
                {
                    resMeg =await client.GetAsync(uri);
                }
                else
                {
                    resMeg =await client.PostAsync(uri, obj);
                }
                lgmr.Log(string.Concat(uri,": Receive Response From WebAPI"), LoggingManager.LogType.Info);
                var Bytes =await resMeg.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                //byte[] mybyteArray = null;
                //Task<byte[]> Bytes = ProcessURLAsync(uri,client);
                lgmr.Log(string.Concat(": Read the Data from WebAPI Response"), LoggingManager.LogType.Info);                               
                return Bytes;
            }
        }
}

public void ConvertIntoZipAndMoveToBackUp(string localPath, string fileName, byte[] zipByteResponse, string code)
    {
        string Destinationpath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OtherEnrollmentsBackUpPath"] + "\\" + code;
        try
        {               
            ZipArchive archive = null;
            if (File.Exists(localPath + "\\" + fileName))
            {
                File.Delete(localPath + "\\" + fileName);
            }
            archive = ZipFile.Open(localPath + "\\" + fileName, ZipArchiveMode.Create);
            archive.Dispose();
            lgmr.Log(string.Concat(serviceName, " ", code, ": Zip File Created", localPath + "\\" + fileName), LoggingManager.LogType.Info);
            File.WriteAllBytes(localPath + "\\" + fileName, zipByteResponse);

            lgmr.Log(string.Concat(serviceName, " ", code, ": Download Zipfile from the WebAPI Response"), LoggingManager.LogType.Info);

            archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(localPath + "\\" + fileName);
            ecount = archive.Entries.Count(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Name));
            strECount = ecount.ToString();
            lgmr.Log(string.Concat(serviceName, " ", code, ": Files Count: ",ecount, localPath + "\\" + fileName), LoggingManager.LogType.Info);
            foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
            {
                if (File.Exists(localPath + "\\" + entry.Name))
                {
                    File.Delete(localPath + "\\" + entry.Name);
                }
                entry.ExtractToFile(localPath + "\\" + entry.Name);
            }
            archive.Dispose();


            File.Move(localPath + "\\" + fileName, Destinationpath + "\\" + code + string.Format("Enrollments-{0:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss.fff}.zip", DateTime.Now));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //File.Delete(localPath + "\\" + fileName);
            //File.Move(localPath + "\\" + fileName, Destinationpath + "\\" + code + string.Format("ZipErrorEnrollments-{0:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss.fff}.zip", DateTime.Now));
            ecount = 0;               
            lgmr.Log(string.Concat(serviceName, " ", code, " ECount:", ecount, ": Failed to ZIP", localPath + "\\" + fileName, "Resend the Request to WebAPI ", ex.Message), LoggingManager.LogType.Info);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things that you can look at.

First, use the `using` statement to create the archive, that will make sure that it gets disposed.

Second, why do you check if the file exists, delete it, then create it with `ZipFile` just to Write it with `File`? Look at [this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/CSharp/System.IO/File/C_File_WriteAllBytes.htm)

Third, use Path class. It will make sure that all your backslashed is correct, and it looks neater.

Fourth, check if a file can be created in the folder

Check if this code gives you the same result.

```
public void ConvertIntoZipAndMoveToBackUp(string localPath, string fileName, byte[] zipByteResponse, string code)
    {
        string Destinationpath = Path.Combine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OtherEnrollmentsBackUpPath"], code);
        try
        {               
            fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName) + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss.fff") + ".zip";  //This will ensure that you have a unique filename to create
            File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(localPath, fileName), zipByteResponse);
            lgmr.Log(string.Concat(serviceName, " ", code, ": Zip File Created and Downloaded from the WebAPI Response", Path.Combine(localPath, fileName)), LoggingManager.LogType.Info);

            using (var archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(Path.Combine(localPath, fileName)))
            {
                ecount = archive.Entries.Count(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Name));
                strECount = ecount.ToString();
                lgmr.Log(string.Concat(serviceName, " ", code, ": Files Count: ",ecount, localPath + "\\" + fileName), LoggingManager.LogType.Info);
                foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
                {
                    if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(localPath, entry.Name)))
                    {
                         File.Delete(Path.Combine(localPath, entry.Name));
                    }
                    entry.ExtractToFile(Path.Combine(localPath, entry.Name));
                }
            }

            File.Move(Path.Combine(localPath, fileName), Path.Combine(Destinationpath, code + string.Format("Enrollments-{0:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss.fff}.zip", DateTime.Now)));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //File.Delete(localPath + "\\" + fileName);
            //File.Move(localPath + "\\" + fileName, Destinationpath + "\\" + code + string.Format("ZipErrorEnrollments-{0:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss.fff}.zip", DateTime.Now));
            ecount = 0;               
            lgmr.Log(string.Concat(serviceName, " ", code, " ECount:", ecount, ": Failed to ZIP", localPath + "\\" + fileName, "Resend the Request to WebAPI ", ex.Message), LoggingManager.LogType.Info);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You probably dont have to restart your PC. just restart the service. Can you run this in debug?

Comment: File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(localPath, fileName), zipByteResponse); // exception here again,

Comment: After the first successful run, can you check if the file was actually moved. Because the only reason you will get this error is because the file was not moved, and you try to create the same file

Comment: how to check file is moved or not?

Comment: After I restart my PC, my background service works fine. 2nd time onwards same exception. there is no ".zip" file inside folder

Comment: Check if the file 'D:\\TMLARS\\OtherLocationEnrollments\\JSR\\JSR_Enrollments.zip' exist after the move occurred. I cannot replicate the error you getting. I'm running the code and i don't get the exception

Comment: but exception was happened File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(localPath, fileName), zipByteResponse);  for this line.

Comment: in test server, it was works fine, for exchanging data through webAPI,

Comment: but exception was happened only in my PC

Comment: I understand. The issue is that the file is still locked by something, so it is very possible that the error is caused by something outside of this method

Comment: i was edited above post, posted full code to get more clarity, foreach was repeated 6 times. i will connect 6 locations, 6 locations havng same background service and 6 WebAPIs

Comment: there is interval time 5 minutes.

Comment: The problem exist because the file is currently locked by another process. Because you use async methods it is very possible that you are trying to create a new file while another process is still busy. I'm making a change to my post. Try that and see what happens

Comment: I've changed the code. Please try that. I've added `fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName) + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss.fff") + ".zip";`

Comment: same  exception access denied

Comment: that folder properties "read only" selected. i thought that is problem

Comment: But then how is it possible that the first time it works fine? That does not make sense. I've updated my answer.

Comment: after restart my pc, first time works fine, was created, entityframework instance globally created, any problem for that?

Comment: i got it. that is problem in my local PC. same local folders are maintain in the network shared, it was works fine.